# Does anyone make filters thin enough for a Voigtländer Bessa III?

Tags: filters, rangefinder

Do you know of any manufacturer that makes filters thin enough so that the can stay on the Voigtländer Bessa III even when folded? I would need yellow, red and polarising filter.

Comment: Do you know how much tolerance you have? Even the "low-profile" Hoya frames are about 3mm thick.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really an answer, but if I had a folding Bessa, I wouldn't do it. But if you're feeling lucky, why not to try the low profile (meant to minimize vignetting on wide-angles) Hoyas? Or any other company that makes low profile filters.